# Probem with implementing my search bar(fuzzywuzzy) flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar, fuzzywuzzy

I'm using the package fuzzywuzzy from flutter and I don't know why but it says my result variable is null.

Can you guys help me and explain why?

I wanted the value of result I tried putting it in an await statement but it says result is null

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> performFuzzySearch(String searchText) async {
    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Question Papers').get();

    final searchResults = querySnapshot.docs.where((doc) {
        print(doc["Keywords"]);
        print(searchText);
        final result = extractOne(query: searchText,
                           choices: doc["Keywords"],
                           cutoff: 10,
                       );
        if (result.score >= 80) {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }).toList();

    searchResults.sort(
        (a, b) => b['Votes'].compareTo(
            a['Votes'],
        ),
    );

    return searchResults;
}
```

My error is with result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If extractOne doesn't find a close enough match it will return a null.
Check if the result is null before accessing its score property.

I've amended your code.  Hopefully, this should work for you.

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> performFuzzySearch(String searchText) async {
  final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Question Papers')
      .get();

  final searchResults = querySnapshot.docs.where((doc) {
    print(doc["Keywords"]);
    print(searchText);
    
    final result = extractOne(
      query: searchText,
      choices: doc["Keywords"],
      cutoff: 10,
    );

    if (result != null && result.score >= 80) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }).toList();

  searchResults.sort(
    (a, b) => b['Votes'].compareTo(a['Votes']),
  );

  return searchResults;
}
```